# How to orient planes around a circle so that they point towards the center using Python?

Tags: python

I have Planes already positioned on the circle and parented with the circle. I'd like to orient them all with the **-Z axis** pointing towards the center of the circle like in the pictures I posted.

I want to make with Python, But I can't find a working solution

**Wrong arrangement:**
[image]

**Right arrangement:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this, but...this is NOT with a parent. So maybe you parent your objects after my code?

```
import bpy
from math import cos,sin,radians,pi

steps = 10

angleStep = radians(360 / steps)

for i in range(0,steps):
    
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
 
    angle = i * angleStep
    
    bpy.context.active_object.location = (cos(angle) * 5, sin(angle) * 5, 0)
    
    bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler = (0,pi/2,angle)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: In the meantime I had found another method, but this one seems much cleaner. It works very well. After this operation I can also parent objects with a parent